# Subshell `(alias; declare -f)` in a function

Tags: bash, function, alias

I defined the following `which` function as recommended in `man which`:

> The recommended way to use this utility is by adding an alias (C shell)
>          or shell function (Bourne shell) like the following:
>
> ```
> which()
> {
>     (alias; declare -f) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot $@
> }
> export -f which
> ```

Unlike  `/usr/bin/which` which only finds commands, this function finds  commands, aliases and functions. My question is why is `(alias; declare -f)` being piped into `/usr/bin/which $@`?

Comment: Why would you do this when you can just use the shell builtin `type`, which finds aliases and functions out of the box?

Comment: Beyond that, could you describe where you got stuck? Try running `alias; declare -f` (or check their documentation) and what they do should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `type`, but how `(alias; declare -f) |` works in this example?

Comment: How do you think it works? It works exactly the way it says it does, spawning a subshell, redirecting its output to a pipe, and running `alias` and then `declare -f` inside it with that output redirected.

Comment: I don't mean to be dismissive or flippant with the "how do you think it works?" comment. If you don't describe the specific nature of your misunderstanding, there's not really a specific question to answer. Without that detail, one doesn't know if you need to have subshells or pipelines explained.

Comment: Typically I use a pipe to pass the stdout of a command into the stdin of another command. But I had never used a subshell containing multiple commands on the left side of a pipe, which motivated my question.

Comment: Are you asking "Why multiple commands?" or "Why in a subshell?"

Comment: Mainly why in a subshell? but also why `which` reads from stdin? I think the answers are (1) the subshell is used to concatenate the output of its commands, an alternative is `{ alias; declare -f }`. (2) `which --read-alias --read-functions $@` compares stdin with `$@`.

Comment: Specifically, uses alias and function definitions on stdin as additional information to use in determining the meaning of the content on `$@` (which is equivalent to an unquoted `$*` and thus buggy; passing through an argument list should always be done as `"$@"`; the quotes are critical).

Comment: Re: "why is it in a subshell?", with very limited exceptions, *all* pipeline components run in subshells. That would be true for a brace group also. The point is just to make both commands part of the same pipeline component.

Comment: I imagine they used a subshell here either because they didn't know better, or because they knew it would be harder for people to mess up (by not requiring spaces and trailing semicolons). There's no technical reason for why it should be in an explicit subshell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/bin/which` is not built into the shell. Consequently, it has no way to access shell-internal state (like aliases or function definitions) unless that content is fed into it.

That's what's being done here.

However, that's *completely unnecessary* on any modern shell. Feeding shell syntax info an external program to be parsed there is innately unreliable compared to having the shell itself give you the output you need.

Don't do this. Use the shell built-in `type` instead.